# Why do some variables need `self.` and others don't, in 1 function?

Tags: python

i am starting my studies on OPP and I am struggling a little to grasp one concept. I believe this is very basic for you guys here, but I was hoping to get some help with it.

I have this code:

```
class Player:
    MAX_POSITION = 10

    def __init__(self):
        self.position = 0

    # Add a move() method with steps parameter     
    def move(self, steps):
        if self.position + steps < Player.MAX_POSITION:
            self.position = self.position + steps 
        else:
            self.position = Player.MAX_POSITION
```

It is correct, it runs... but I am struggling to learn why I need the prefix `self` on the `position` argument and not on the `steps` within the function `move` for the class `Player`?

any explanations or reading material suggestions are more than welcome
thanks

Comment: @MauriceMeyer. I don't think the answer is right for OP, it's more about when class variable has the same name as instance attribute.

Comment: `steps` is a variable name (as is `self`, in Python) - in this case an argument to the `move` method. There is no variable called `position`, but it does exist as a property on the class instance, which by convention is called `self`.

Comment: `position` is a property of _the instance on which the method is called_ (which is represented by the parameter `self`). Meanwhile, `steps` is just a variable

Comment: `position` is not an argument, it's an attribute. Does that answer your question, or do you need help understanding these terms as well? Please [edit] to clarify, and write a better title while you're there, for example *'Why do I need "self" on one argument but not another?'*, if that's what you're asking. For tips, see [ask].

Comment: (Aaargh, I just voted to close as "unclear" but there were already two duplicate votes so it closed as duplicate, but it's obviously not a duplicate so I reopened it but now I can't vote to close again.)

Comment: Why the race to close a question that's perfectly clear? Feel free to edit the title if you feel it needs improvement (I will do so now)

Comment: @Grismar IMHO it's not clear if OP just misread the code and thought `position` is an argument, or if it's deeper than that. But the new title is a great improvement, thanks :)

Comment: @wjandrea, I am sorry my question was not clear enough, as I mentioned, I am still learning OPP, so I was not sure how to ask the question. 
Grismar, really appreciate the help here!

I see Grismar answered below, I am going to study his answer and lget better at asking as well, thanks all

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In an example like this:

```
def class MyClass:
    def __init__():
        self.attribute = None

    def my_method(self, some_parameter):
        self.attribute = some_parameter
```

`attribute` is defined as an attribute (or *instance variable*) on `MyClass`. This means that every instance of `MyClass` (a `MyClass` object) will have its own copy of `attribute`.

Since every normal method (a function defined on the class) expects the first argument to be the object itself (which you don't have to pass; Python will pass it automatically), you can use `self` to refer to the instance the method was called on. (I say 'normal', because there are also 'static' and 'class' methods, but forget about those for now.)

So, in this example:

```
an_object = MyClass()
an_object.my_method(10)
print(an_object.attribute)
```

This works, because in the body of `.my_method`, the passed value, which gets assigned to `some_parameter` is assigned to the `attribute` attribute of `an_object`, because `an_object` is assigned to `self` in that call. Mind you, `self` could have been called anything; naming the first parameter `self` is just a convention you should follow.

The reason `some_parameter` does not need `self.` is because it is just another parameter of a function. It's not an attribute of `self` — of the object the method was called on.

So, when compared to your code, you should say: `steps` does not need `self.` because it is not an attribute of a `Player` instance. It is just a parameter of a method defined on `Player`, and the value is accessible like any parameter is in a function body. The instance of a `Player` object is passed as `self`, and you can change its attributes by accessing them on `self` inside the function body.

A clue why you didn't grasp this is that you call `position` an 'argument', but an argument is something passed to a function, to a specific parameter; and a parameter is an internal variable of a function that is assigned the argument. `position` is an attribute of an object.

So, when calling `player.move(2)`, `2` is the *argument*, `steps` is the *parameter* in the body of `move()` and `position` is the *attribute* of `player`, with `player` being the `Player` class *instance* (or '*object*') accessible through the `self` parameter in the body of `move()`.

Comment: Best explanation I have ever encountered for the subject!

Comment: Indeed. Very clear and comprohensive explanation.

Answer (score -1):

Recently I faced quite similar problem and when searching the answer I stumbled your question and comprehensive answer given above by **Grismar**.
I just want to bring here some practical examples that will show a bit more and reveal under-the-hood gears.

Let's start with your code. If we call a few instances like below this will bring us a correct result.

```py
p1 = Player()
p1.move(100)
print('p1.__dict__ ->', p1.__dict__)

p2 = Player()
p2.move(1)
print('p2.__dict__ ->', p2.__dict__)

# output
# p1.__dict__ -> {'position': 10}
# p2.__dict__ -> {'position': 1}
```

Notations `p1.__dict__` and `p2.__dict__` show what values are actually assigned to a `position` variable.

So, what if we would like to use variable `steps` somewhere in another method (or methods)? I modified your code just a bit by adding additional method `jump()` to demonstrate what will happen.

This code **will not** work correctly for the method `jump()`. But the method `move()` still correctly executed.

```py
class Player:
    MAX_POSITION = 10

    def __init__(self):
        self.position = 0

    # Add a move() method with steps parameter     
    def move(self, steps):
        if self.position + steps < Player.MAX_POSITION:
            self.position = self.position + steps 
        else:
            self.position = Player.MAX_POSITION

    def jump(self):
        print(steps * 2)


p1 = Player()
p1.move(100)
print('p1.__dict__ ->', p1.__dict__)
p1.jump()

# output
# p1.__dict__ -> {'position': 10}
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# NameError: name 'steps' is not defined
```

To fix the problem and remove exception (here it is `NameError: name 'steps' is not defined`) we have to «glue» `self` and `steps`.

```py
class Player:
    MAX_POSITION = 10

    def __init__(self):
        self.position = 0

    # Add a move() method with steps parameter     
    def move(self, steps):
        self.steps = steps # added line
        if self.position + steps < Player.MAX_POSITION:
            self.position = self.position + steps 
        else:
            self.position = Player.MAX_POSITION

    def jump(self):
        print('jump() method ->', self.steps * 2) # added self


p1 = Player()
p1.move(100)
print('p1.__dict__ ->', p1.__dict__)
p1.jump()

# output
# p1.__dict__ -> {'position': 10, 'steps': 100}
# jump() method -> 200
```

Now we can see that the method `move()` executed correctly (variable `position` assigned to `10`). The method `jump()` executed without any exceptions as well. Instance `p1` has now two available variables, they are `'position': 10` and `'steps': 100`.
In other words `self.variable` notation gives the option to use the variable beyond the «parent» method.